# How to asynchronously execute a Future that precedes another Future

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am making nested calls to an API. The final result is several thousand calls. The end consumer of this expects an iterator like so:

`Iterator[Map[String,String]]`

I don't want to run over every single leaf call before handing over to the next stage.

At the next state the iterator is consumed by a different method that inserts each `Map` as a row into a db.

Because that `Iterator` may be large and may contain bad rows that cause failures, the ingestion method `ingestIterator` also returns a `Future`

`def ingestIterator(i: Iterator[Map[String,String]]): Seq[CustomFuture[Boolean]]`

so the whole thing looks like

```
def getStates(url:String): List[String]

def getCounties(states: List[String]): List[String]

def getBlocks(stateCounties: List[String]): Iterator[Map[String,String]]

def getEverything(): Future[Iterator[Map[String, String]]]
```

but the `ingestIterator` wants an iterator and I'm trying to figure out what is the best practice for inserting asynchronicity in the middle here.

Comment: Add Futures in all of those functions

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate each `Map[String, String]` lazily only when the result iterator is being consumed then your processing is actually sequential and probably you'll not get any boost from futures.

In fact seems that you want a combination of parallelism and backpressure. 
Take a look at streaming libraries like `fs2`, `zio-streams` or `akka-streams`.